# error.runtime.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError , Error processing request, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/speech/v1/SpeechClient

Tags: google-speech-to-text-api

I have run Speech to text standalone application successfully on eclipse but now I integrated the same with my vxml application and deployed on tomcat but at the run time I am facing below issue.

What could be the reason .

error.runtime.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ,  Error processing request, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/speech/v1/SpeechClient

Tomcat version : 8.5
Java version:1.8.0.231

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>`
    </dependency>
```

Thanks & regards
Tarun Jain